# Meaning of "Procedure-valued variable?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

What does it meant by a procedure-valued variable in the programming language context .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a variable contains a procedure? Like in functional languages, where you can sth like:

```
variable f = new function(int x) { return x*2; } 
int i = f(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard this term. But from what I've gathered via google (e.g. http://thid.thesa.com/thid-0513-0671-th-1411-0895, http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/17/1/38.full.pdf), it seems a pretty obscure and old term for or variables of a "callback" or "function" type - a variable that contains a (kind of reference to a) function/procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, a variable, the value of which is a procedure. Many modern programming languages support this notion. For example, C has function pointers:

```
void foo()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int main()
{
    void (*funcp)(void);  // pointer to function
    funcp = foo;
    funcp();
}
```

Python:

```
def foo():
    print 'Hello, world!'

f = foo  // assign foo (a function) to variable foo
f()
```

Comment: C isn't modern. And Lisp is ancient but supports this as well.

Comment: @delnan: C is in common use as a programming language and a new standard is in the works. And yes, Lisp had this back in the late '50s.